# How to reference multiple sub elements using ansible?

Tags: loops, ansible, nested-loops

I've got an ansible playbook with the following vars structure:

```
TESTS:
  - name: test1
    hosts: ['host_one', 'host_two', 'host_three']
    services: ['service1, 'service2, 'service3']
  - name: test2
    hosts: ['host_four', 'host_five', 'host_six']
    services: ['service4, 'service5, 'service6']
```

This is the kind of task I want to do, but of course `with_subelements` only allows one subkey. I've been trying to use `with_nested` but struggling quite a lot.

```
- name: check services on each host
  systemd:
     name: "{{item.1}}"
     state: started
  delegate_to: "{{item.2}}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{TESTS}}"
    - services
    - hosts
```

I want each service to be checked on each of the corresponding hosts.
eg.

```
test1: 
service1 on host_one,host_two,host_three
service2 on host_one,host_two,host_three
service3 on host_one,host_two,host_three

test2: 
service4 on host_four,host_five,host_six
service5 on host_four,host_five,host_six
service6 on host_four,host_five,host_six
```

Comment: Make a proper inventory of your hosts, then you can have a sub elements on the services

Comment: dont forget to close your question by validating the right answer...

Answer (score 1):

when to tranform data is complex i prefer to use a custom plugin:

create a file **my_filter.py** in the folder **filter_plugins** (same level than your playbook) and give customfilter as name:

my_filter.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'customfilter': self.customfilter
        }
 
    def customfilter(self, obj):
        result = []
        for rec in obj:
            for ser in rec["services"]:
                for host in rec["hosts"]:
                    result.append({ "name":rec["name"], "service":ser, "host":host })
        #print(result)
        return result
```

playbook to use the custom filter:

```
- name: "make this working"
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    TESTS:
      - name: test1
        hosts: ['host_one', 'host_two', 'host_three']
        services: ['service1', 'service2', 'service3']
      - name: test2
        hosts: ['host_four', 'host_five', 'host_six']
        services: ['service4', 'service5', 'service6']

  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ TESTS | customfilter }}"
```

for your playbook:

```
- name: check services on each host: {{ item.name }}
  systemd:
     name: "{{item.service}}"
     state: started
  delegate_to: "{{item.host}}"
  loop: "{{ TESTS | customfilter }}"
```